# How to get Product Key for Visual Studio 2010 from MSDNAA without downloading?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, license, visual-studio, product-key, software-activation

I've installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional Trial from [the public ISO download site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16057). Then I noticed that I don't have a Product Key yet so I logged in to DreamSpark with my MSDNAA login (that is provided to me by my school's license/contract). I 'bought' VS2010 Professional (for $0 with school license). Now it tells me that I should proceed and download the image and then burn it on a disk.

**Is there a way to obtain my product key without downloading Visual Studio 2010 again, from MSDNAA?**

I have it installed and ready, really, but I need my product key so I could activate it. I have one legally, but I want to avoid downloading 2+ GBs and going through re-installation just for obtaining a string < 128 bytes.

The confirmation letter says that I should reach any serial numbers or activation keys within my account; however, following the link it gives me, I arrive at the Order Details page that only gives me Order Number and Agreement Number, a "start download" button and a text that I have 24 months of access, but without actually giving me the key.

Comment: @MattH for clarification: I've *never* entered any key for this product yet. This would be the first time. Currently I'm running in the evaluation period.

Comment: ahh, sorry I misunderstood the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to obtain my product key without downloading Visual
>   Studio 2010 again, from MSDNAA?

The product is tied into the iso.  You would have to download the iso in order to get this information.  Its unique to your account.

> I have it installed and ready, really, but I need my product key so I
>   could activate it. I have one legally, but I want to avoid downloading
>   2+ GBs and going through re-installation just for obtaining a string <
>   128 bytes.

You have no other option if you want the product key.

> The confirmation letter says that I should reach any serial numbers or
>   activation keys within my account; however, following the link it
>   gives me, I arrive at the Order Details page that only gives me Order
>   Number and Agreement Number, a "start download" button and a text that
>   I have 24 months of access, but without actually giving me the key.

The product key is contained within a file contained in the iso its a silent installation, the best way to solve this, is to simply reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems sad but true.

Comment: @naxa - There might be a way, I just don't know it, but to escape only a 2GB download it doesn't seem worth the trouble.  In previous versions of products they used to provide a key.

Comment: Then just for the record: if anyone knows a way, I value adventure. :)